# xsl want to transform the following xml to html:

Tags: xslt

```
<!ELEMENT TITLE      (CDATA | ELEMENTX )+  >
```

If I use the below then when 
   TITLE contains CDATA and 
   ELEMENTX contains CDATA I get duplicate text.
How should a template for this element TITLE be written?

```
<xsl:template match="TITLE">
  <span>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name()='ELEMENT1'"> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each> 
   </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Allow me to suggest you to kindly provide examples of what you have tried so far. A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and then [edit] your question to get the most out of stackoverflow.

Comment: Bascially what you see in the question is what I tried. When TITLE only has a CDATA this works but when TITLE does not have CDATA but a child element I get the data written twice. Is there a way to detect an element having CDATA ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, it seems that you are stuck when mixed type of content allowed in DTD, and you are handling when CDATA appear and face issue if there is further child elements.

If you are suppose to push all child inside `p` then you can use `<xsl:apply-templates/>`
 and handle further data in template.

If you only require for handle your code for CDATA updation then use

```
    <p>
        <xsl:if test="text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </p>
```

instead of

```
<p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do exactly what I need. 
It puts out the Text from the parent element TITLE if any before any child element. Then it works on a child element if any and then puts out any text in the parent before the next child and so on.

```
<xsl:template match="TITLE">
  <span>
  <xsl:for-each select="* | ./text()">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="local-name()=''">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="local-name()='ELEMENT1'"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each> 
  </span>
</xsl:template>
```